# Spring Integration: replying messages with gateways

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http, spring-integration-ws

I have this Spring Integration code that receives a SOAP message and then replies it.

This is the configuration:

```
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel wsGatewayInboundChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel wsGatewayOutboundChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow soapMessageFlow(SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(webServiceInboundGateway)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
            .channel(SOAP_MESSAGE_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway() {
    SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway simpleWebServiceInboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway();
    simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(wsGatewayInboundChannel());
    simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setReplyChannel(wsGatewayOutboundChannel());
    simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setExtractPayload(false);
    simpleWebServiceInboundGateway.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    return simpleWebServiceInboundGateway;
  }
```

And this is the service that processes the message:

```
@Service
public class SoapMessageService {

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SOAP_MESSAGE_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME, outputChannel = GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME)
  public SoapMessage receive(SoapMessage request) {
    //...
    return reply;
  }
}
```

This works fine.

I don't know how the reply channel works behind the curtains, but I want to be really sure that replies don't mix up. For instance, if I receive:

```
Request_1 from A, which reply is Reply_1
Request_2 from B, which reply is Reply_2
```

I want Reply_1 to be delivered to A and Reply_2 to be delivered to B and NOT Reply_1 being delivered to B and Reply_2 being delivered to A.

Can reply channel guarantee the behaviour previously described?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do guarantee. The gateway implementation in Spring Integration us fully based on the `Return Address` EI pattern: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ReturnAddress.html.

Every gateway request is set with a `replyChannel` header to the `TemporaryReplyChannel`. When no `outputChannel` configured downstream, the framework consults that header to deliver the current message.

In most cases we really don't need that `setReplyChannel` to be configured on the inbound gateway. Just because we simply can rely on the `replyChannel` header.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-default-reply-channel

And also this GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3985

There see if it would make sense for your to get rid off that `GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME` at all everywhere.